# Meaning of "power granted to the commander-in-chief ... also be a troubling one"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[Trump's authority crisis deepens](https://news.google.com/articles/CAIiEMgnX-A4lftSB2hZ6SL6XEoqGQgEKhAIACoHCAowocv1CjCSptoCMPrTpgU?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen)

> But the idea that there is a core of "adults in the room," as
>   described by the op-ed writer, subverting the President’s authority
>   and wielding for themselves **the power granted to the commander-in-chief** during an election season should also **be a troubling one**, since it raises questions about the integrity of
>   America’s democratic system itself.
>
> power granted to the commander-in-chief

"commander-in-chief" here means Trump, right?

The power granted to Trump "during an election season"? Wasn't it granted to Trump after he took the office? I think "power granted to the commander-in-chief during an election season" is not one sentence, split it to "power granted to the commander-in-chief" and "during an election season".

> be a troubling one

trouble for who?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commander-in-chief certainly *is* Trump, as it is one of the roles of the president of the United States: at least in principle, he commands the armed forces of the United States.

The problem that is sketched by the author, is that some other people are effectively taking over that power.

That means trouble in general, for everyone. Literally, for the world. More specifically, the author questions whether such a situation would be a good one for the United States and its citizens, who are represented by the president. It should be the president who is responsible for taking military decisions, but now it seems some self-styled "adults in the room" take up responsibility for carrying out his job.

Apart from the possible effects of a president on the country's internal state of affairs or its economic relationships with other countries, one of the common fears about the power of the American president is that they have the power to declare war, and ultimately, take the decision to use nuclear weapons. This is sometimes expressed as "he has the red button" (to launch missiles). 
Having Trump in that position is seen by some/many as dangerous, but the author of this article points out it may be even more troublesome to have some group of non-elected people take over this role. At least the president can be (partly) controlled by the rule of law.

Comment: The President does not have the power to "declare war", at least not formally. That power is reserved to the Congress. But the President has been granted by Congress the power to initiate military action on a very large scale, so for all intents and purposes Congress has abrogated its role in this regard,

Answer (score 0):

Commander-in-Chief does refer to Trump. The President of the USA is automatically the Commander-in-Chief of the Armed Forces. The writer is concerned that these non-elected 'adults in the room' are using the power and authority of the elected President. The writer believes that this should be of concern to everyone, but especially those who believe in the American democratic system.

Answer (score -3):

"commander-in-chief" is not Trump, it's the chief of the core of "adults in the room."
To grant the power to the chief of the core would cause trouble for the country during an election season.

Comment: Commander-in-chief is one of the roles of the president of the United States. So, yes, that _is_ Trump. The problem lies in the fact that that power is now wielded by someone else, but that doesn't make them C-in-C.